# HttpTestingController fails with Failed to Match Criteria

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have created a UserService which saves a user to the database. I also have a service which pre-configures the endpoints, for local , qa, uat and prod called UrlService. This class returns in a promise the URls using APP_INITIALIZER, which works fine. It seems the configuration in the assets folder urls.json is interfering with the tests. When I added a console.log in the matches method, it prints out the path in /asset/urls.json. I don't understand how this could be interfering with my tests.  I am perplexed this would have any bearing on my tests, but any insight will help.

When I run my tests it fails with the error:

```
    Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match by function: ", found 2 requests. I print out the URL and it matches what gets printed in the service and it matches the one in the test.
```

How can the urls not match? I am completely confused by this?
Does anyone have any idea how this can be?

```
  export class UserDetail{
   name: string;
   department: string;
   userId: string;
  }

  saveUser(
     user: UserDetail,
     url: string
   ): Observable<UserDetail> {
     return this.http
     .post<UserDetail>(
      url,
      user,
      this.httpOptions
    )
    .pipe(
       tap(
        (resp: UserDetail) =>
        console.log(`New User ${user}`),
       (error) => {
        console.log('Received an error', error);    
       }
       )
     );
     console.log('URL passed is ', url); 
  }

   it("Create User", fakeAsync(() => {
      user = {
          name: "Ranger",
          department: "Merch",
          userId: "1222222",
       };
         let response = null;
         const URL = urlService.getConfig().userLocal;
         userService.saveUser(user, URL).subscribe(
         (expectedResponse) => {
           response = expectedResponse;
         },
        (error: any) => {}
      );
      const req = httpMock.expectOne((request) => {
      console.log("URL is: ", request.url);
       return true;
      });
      const requestWrapper = httpMock.expectOne({
      url: URL,
      });
       requestWrapper.flush(user);
       tick();
       expect(requestWrapper.request).toBeTruthy();
       expect(requestWrapper.request.method).toEqual("POST");
       expect(response.request).toBeTruthy();
      }));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `httpMock` is triggered twice, so when you `expectOne` it fails and throws the error message you showed: `... found 2 requests.`.

To solve this you can define the expected request, something similar to:

```
httpMock.expectOne((request) => 
    return request.method === 'POST' && request.url === URL;
);
```

**Edit**:
Let me further explain, if you make two calls with HttpClient, and in your test, expectOne, your test will fail with the error message you are receiving.

See an example with this service:

```
export class DataServiceService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  testSingleCall() {
    return this.httpClient.get('/data').subscribe();
  }

  testDoubleCalls() {
    this.httpClient.get('/data').subscribe();
    this.httpClient.get('/data').subscribe();
  }
}
```

and here is the test file:

```
it('should test httpmock', () => {
  service.testSingleCall();
  
  // If no request with that URL was made, or if multiple requests match, expectOne() would throw.
  httpMock.expectOne("/data");
});

it('should test httpmock multiple calls', () => {
  service.testDoubleCalls();

  const requests = httpMock.match("/data");
  expect(requests.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

if you run `httpMock.expectOne("/data")` on `testDoubleCalls()` the test will fail because the service is making two calls and the test expects there to be only a single call.

Comment: Hi, do you mean this call?    const req = httpMock.expectOne((request) => {
                                              console.log("URL is: ", request.url);
                                              return true;
                                            });,  It was failing before adding that call

Comment: its either that call or the other one (const requestWrapper = httpMock.expectOne({
      url: URL,
      }); - both are expecting a single call (expectOne) but are getting two calls - the same two calls

Comment: Thank you, let me investigate that.

Comment: @BreenDeen - I've added a longer explanation, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks a ton, really appreciated!!